# How do I retrieve my custom logger by class name and output the actual class name from multiple places?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

The following syntax seem to be accepted for retrieveing a logger from log4net:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

because it avoids having to hard-code the specific type of the class logging:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

I do understand that point, and also that you can create your own logger and use that one, by matching the name
such as:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("MyCustomLogger");
```

using configuration:

```
<logger name="MyCustomLogger">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

But, if I at some other place also would like to retrieve the *same* logger but with a different name:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeOtherPlace");
```

How would I approach this?
I want to write `MyCustomLogger` as well as `SomeOtherPlace` to the file, to distinguish from where in the code the logging happened.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You want to apply quoted configuration to all your loggers?

Comment: @joozek I tried to clarify the question, see the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the assembly name for the logger it will match.

Since your call to `LogManager.GetLogger` will search for a logger matching the fully-qualified name of the class, you can match it with your custom logger if you in the configuration name the logger according to the assembly.

```
<logger name="My.Special.Assembly">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

Assuming the above configuration, the following code would find and use your logger

```
namespace My.Special.Assembly.With
{
    public class MyType
    {
        public MyType()
        {
            var log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }
    }
}
```

I.e, log4net will find logger My.Special.Assembly with the following call:

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("My.Special.Assembly.With.MyType");
```

Comment: True, but the name of the logger doesn't _have_ to be the assembly name, it could just as easily be `BaseLogger` which would be used by loggers `BaseLogger.MyCustomLogger` and `BaseLogger.SomeOtherPlace`

Comment: @stuartd Yes you're correct, I just find it convenient to use the assembly name because it fits well with the reflection call which returns the fully-qualified namespace.

Comment: Ah I hadn't noticed you were answering your own question, so you know what you need :)